# Can ImageMagick make my grayscale image brighter by "compressing" the black-to-white range to dark-gray-to-white?

Tags: imagemagick

I have a grayscale image with pixels ranging from black to white. I'd like to make it brighter by moving the "black floor" up, and scaling the other pixel intensities. I'd prefer linear scaling but it's not too important. Is this possible with ImageMagick?

Answer (score 0):

*Which OS? Linux assumed below.*

Generally the effects on one image may or may not apply to another image, simply because they're different.

Below you have a selection of the effects that `convert` can apply, one or more of them **may** do what you want, to your image(s). *(`man convert` shows these, you need to look up a tutorial to get to know how to use them.)*

```
-auto-gamma          automagically adjust gamma level of image
-auto-level          automagically adjust color levels of 
-contrast            enhance or reduce the image contrast
-contrast-stretch geometry
                     improve contrast by 'stretching' the intensity range
-linear-stretch geometry
                     improve contrast by `stretching with saturation' the intensity range
-sigmoidal-contrast geometry
                     lightness rescaling using sigmoidal contrast enhancement
```

Comment: Mmmm, none of these are even close to what OP is asking for. Gamma and sigmoidal are both non-linear. Auto-level just chops to lowest and highest luminance. And the answer is the same on Linux, macOS or Windows.

Comment: Yes.... ;-D Thanks for the confidence in my skills. What method you use might depend quite a bit on your needs. Based on the Q-text I went for simple choices...

Comment: I didn't down-vote your answer... 

Comment: Well, that was kind of you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `+level` command for this. Let's make a full-scale black-white gradient to start with:

```
magick -size 400x400 gradient:black-white start.jpg
```

[image]

I have artificially added a small red border so you can see its full extent on StackExchange's stupid background.

Now, suppose you want to move the black-point up from 0 to 40% black, but leave the white-point unchanged at 100% and linearly scale everything in between:

```
magick start.jpg +level 40,100% result.jpg
```

[image]

---

Note that if you don't specify the upper level, it assumes it is the same as the lower level, so this will chop 40% off ***both*** ends of the black-white scale:

```
magick start.jpg +level 40% result.jpg
```

[image]

---

If you a re familiar with Photoshop Levels/Curves, I am suggesting the equivalent of the white line in this curve:

[image]